# cuda double chevron such as 1<<20?

Tags: syntax, cuda

Can someone please explain to me what does the double chevron in 
`Kernel<<<32*SM, 256>>>(1 << 20, 2.0, x, y);` 
do?

Comment: I suggest removing `cuda` and `gpgpu` tags, and adding `c` tag. Note the question is specifically about the `<<` operator.

Comment: i think its actually better to keep it tbh, think there will be people who comes up with this problem in cuda and not sure if it is what they think it is, and this will give them a confirmation, if someone is searching about c bitshifting they will be easily find thousands of threads about it. just my opinion tho, if u guys think i should change i will

Answer (score 3):

The **triple-chevron** is the syntax for launching a kernel - scheduling it for execution by the GPU. See the first example in the CUDA [Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) (sec 3.2.2) . The **double chevron** is just the usual left-shift operator - it's not CUDA-related, it's an argument for the kernel function (i.e. the argument is 1048576 or 2^20).

(Just so you know, the use of the triple-chevron is completely arbitrary, there isn't any philosophical justification behind it - that I know of, anyway. So don't expect any other weird chevron combination to mean anything CUDA-specific.)

Comment: yeh thanks for helping out, i was just reading up some code without a machine to test on so i just have to ask here, tbh triple chevron was such a bad idea i have no idea why they choosed it, on my program i just macro them into something better looking.

Comment: @RockyZhang: A former coworker of mine said he thinks they may have done it to get a patent or something. By the way, you can essentially avoid it if you like, see [this](https://bitbucket.org/eyalroz/kernel-tester/src/1dfc1880efb1a1e59e1d5929222f78cb7a4a9c1e/src/cuda/kernel_launch_wrapper.cuh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) nice templated wrapper.

Comment: @einpoklum 1-click is a *process*. Triple chevron isn't. You can't patent syntax.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Perhaps you're right but this is degenerating into a chat, so... let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit shift. 1 shifted 20 times. Nothing specific to cuda. It's a c/c++ notation

Comment: lol i thought it was something else, it all make sense now thank you